# Tomcat : Error during execution : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/GenericFilter

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, server, dependencies

I am getting the errors below :

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/snow]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1018)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:994)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:2002)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/GenericFilter
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3251)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1924)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:106)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5709)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.GenericFilter
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1955)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
        ... 22 more
```

When I have in my pom.xml this dependency :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried to follow some people suggestions to add `<scope>provided</scope>` , but still this does not work.

What could cause such errors ?

Thank in advance

Comment: Looks like you're deploying a war file, not running a jar file with embedded Tomcat, is that correct? If so, you're not including the embedded tomcat in that war file, are you?

Comment: You are correct i am deploying a war file , but what do you mean to include the embedded tomcat ? Inside the war I see all Jars including the servlet. 
Sorry if my question sounds stupid , but i am a bit new with tomcat ,still learning.

Comment: Did you follow the instruction in section [**Packaging Executable Jar and War Files**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) of the **Spring Boot Reference Documentation**. --- Specifically the part starting with  *"To build a war file ..."*

Comment: *FYI:* In a war file you should not be seeing the servlet jar file.

Comment: OK thanks for the link , I will check it out first :) , after that will see how I will progress.